# Count Ifs for Unique Values based on Unique Name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of records submitted by customers and my list of records contains duplicate submissions.

What formula can I use in a macro to count the list of unique records based on each customer?

See my example data

```
Record Name       Submitted By           Status
Lead-123           Peter H               Rejected
Lead-495           Carlos Sinbad         Rejected
Lead-496           Carlos Sinbad         Approved
Lead-101           Timothy Johnson       Approved
Lead-421       Timothy Johnson       Approved
Lead-421       Timothy Johnson       Approved
Lead-421       Timothy Johnson       Approved
Lead-421       Timothy Johnson       Rejected
Lead-393       Derik Fauster         Recalled
Lead-393       Derik Fauster         Approved
Lead-422       Derik Fauster         Rejected
Lead-422       Derik Fauster         Rejected
Lead-422       Derik Fauster         Rejected
```

What I want

```
# of Unique Records Submitted     Submitted By 
1                                 Peter H 
2                                 Carlos Sinbad
2                                 Timothy Johnson
2                                 Derik Fauster
```

I have tried this

```
Sub CountUniqueValues()
Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, List As Object
LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each Rng In Range("A2:A" & LstRw)
  If Not List.Exists(Rng.Value) Then List.Add Rng.Value, Nothing
Next

MsgBox "There are " & List.Count & " unique values in column A from row 2 down."

End Sub
```

But I can only get the unique records for Record Name and I can't tie it with a unique Submitted By.

Comment: use a pivot table.

Comment: I have a list of over 1000 records.

And when I do create a pivot table I'll have to carry those values onto another worksheet.

I'd rather use a formula so that I can simply place my values onto my intended worksheet.

Comment: Then please show what you have tried and where it errors so we can help you overcome the error.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me site.

Comment: `
Sub CountUniqueValues()
Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range, List As Object
LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each Rng In Range("A2:A" & LstRw)
  If Not List.Exists(Rng.Value) Then List.Add Rng.Value, Nothing
Next

MsgBox "There are " & List.Count & " unique values in column A from row 2 down."

End Sub
`

Comment: I can get the list of unique values for Record Name but I can't tie it into the Submitted By field.

Comment: Please [edit] the post with clarifications, not in the comments.  Comments cannot be formatted.

Comment: This is exactly what pivot tables are for.  Using another method is like using a hammer for screws.  Can be done but not logical.

Comment: If you really don't want to use a pivot table, set up a query and run SQL on your data.

Comment: I think you've almost got it.  You just need to change your dictionary key value pair to `List.Add Rng.Value, Rng.Offset(1,0)`  Which would tie the unique record with the person submitting it.  Then you could loop over your dictionary to pull each key and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question. I am able to count unique records based on a name criteria.

Below is my modified code that captures all the data in my range and counts the records accordingly.

```
Dim lnNumber2 As Long
Dim rnFormula2 As Range


With ActiveSheet
    lnNumber2 = .Range("B5000").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rnFormula2 = .Range("I15:I" & lnNumber2)
    rnFormula2.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(((Sheet2!R2C2:R5000C2=Sheet1!RC[-7]))/COUNTIFS(Sheet2!R2C1:R5000C1,Sheet1!R2C1:R5000C1&"""",Sheet2!R2C2:R5000C2,Sheet2!R2C2:R5000C2&""""))"

End With
```